# Can i check login screen when only enter authorized users in iPad simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am the bigenner of iOS developer, i am creating login screen.but i want checking only authorized users.otherwise don't go to next view.

Thanks&Regard 
sai5

Answer (score 1):

Its definitely possible but your question is not clear on how you want to authenticate and proceed. basically if your login screen has a button along with two textfields for username and password. The code for the button action will look something like this

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonPressed:(id)sender {
   NSString *username = usernameField.text;
   NSString *password = passwordField.text;
   // Check values and authenticate. Your logic for authentication goes here. Generally you post these data to web service and handle the response to get what you want
   //Do something
   if(validated) {
      //Dom something.
      // In your case show next view
   }
   else {
     //Do something else 
   }
}
```

Where validated is a Bool which indicates if the user is authenticated or not.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For server side:-
You must be using some script in which you send username and password and you get response.When you get response then your some response method will get called , in that method what you have to do is  first:-just communicate with the person you has made server side scripts for you and asked the condition when successful aunthentication is done . second:-Put a check for that condition in your method , if it is true then move to the next view or show some error message.